# Android: AppBarLayout gradient background

Tags: android, background, android-5.0-lollipop, gradient, transparent

I tried implementing a toolbar with gradient background (from black to transparent). The toolbar is inside an AppBarLayout, which is inside a CoordinatorLayour, because I want the Toolbar to slide off the screen when scrolling the screen (hance the scroll|enterAlways scroll flags). This works perfectly fine for pre-lollipop versions and looks like this:

[image]

But on lollipop this is what is displayed:

[image: weird upside down trapezoid in the background]

I tried other combinations of backgrounds on the toolbar and appbarlayout to get the toolbar to have the gradient background, but everything produces the same result. I tried searching for similar problems and found none.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            ...

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180119

Comment: Seems like a similar problem, but I don't use elevation and the visual results look even worse.

Comment: did you have solution for it now? i'm got to the same problem!

Comment: Nope, no solution yet, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5):

AppBarLayout forces an elevation. Since the toolbar is inside AppBarLayout and the toolbar is transparent, the  side and bottom shadow of AppBarLayout became obvious.

Include `app:elevation="0dp"` inside your AppBarLayout. Hope it helps.

Comment: be sure that you use http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto as the url of "xmlns:app"

Comment: Thanks. I just want to add that this also works in the case when setting a background color value with alpha. Without having to set app:elevation="0dp" while setting a background color with alpha value, the color around each side of border is darker than the rest of the appbarlayout area. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put Toolbar and TabLayout inside the LinearLayout and set background attributes for LinearLayout as below code. It's worked and I used this code for my app.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/appbar_bg">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```